# Jquery ajax POST response is null

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, null

I want to get the url in this [link](http://www.panet.co.il/series/seriesLink/138099):

**CODE**:

```
<div id="id01"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: "http://www.panet.co.il/series/seriesLink/138099",
      success: function(info){
      document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = info.data.url ;
    }
   });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the response. When you use **JSONP** the response result must be wrapped inside a `jsonCallback()` function:

```
jsonCallback({"Name": "Foo", "Id": 1234, "Rank": 7});
```

Look for more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: thanks for your answer , so how can i get the url can you write the code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the returned data can't be parsed correctly. Here's my error message in Google Chrome:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

The data returned from http://www.panet.co.il/series/seriesLink/138099 has some UTF8 characters in it. Maybe that's the cause.